# I get a different result with mul instruction in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I have this set of instructions in assembly.

```
   mov ax,0055h
   mov bx,11AAh
   mul al
   xchg ax,bx
   not ax
   neg bx
```

I don't understand the mul instruction in third line.If I do 0055h*11AAh I get 5DD72 but it's not correct because with a program I get in AX 1C39.How ? What's the procedure?

I know that AX and BX are 16 bit registers and my result should be on 32 bit and the result is on DX:AX

Comment: You used `mul al` not `mul bx`. As such you calculated `55h*55h=1C39h`.

Comment: I got it.Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single argument form of `mul` will multiply the argument with `al`/`ax`/`eax`/`rax` depending on the operand size and store the result in `ax`/`dx:ax`/`edx:eax`/`rdx:rax` accordingly.

`mul al` will multiply `al` with `al` and store the result in `ax`. You want `mul bx`.